# Позиционирование JFrame

Tags: java, javafx, swing, jframe

Проблема такая:
Установлена **Windows 10**
Имеется экран **1920x1080 px**
По умолчанию windows ставит **zoom 125%** = **120dpi** для этого разрешения (ну да и бог с ним)
Zoom 125% делает экран **1536x864 px**
Приложение держится на **Java 9 - JavaFX + Swing**

Я вывожу на экран два фрейма одинаковых размеров по обеим сторонам на верху и вот такая вот картина:

Для обоих фреймов (может важно):

```
setAlwaysOnTop(true);
setSize(500, 252);
```

Устанавливаю для `frameRight`:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice defaultScreen = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
Rectangle rect = defaultScreen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
int x = (int) rect.getMaxX() - frameRight.getWidth();
jframe.setLocation(x, 0);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите остается пространство и фрейм не доходит до конца.
Причем со **100% zoom = 80dpi** естественно все норм.
Я уже пробовал что-то типа:

```
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
for (int i = 0; i < dim.width; i++) {
    if (frameRight.getLocation().x + frameRight.getWidth() == dim.width) {
        log.info(frameRight.getLocation().x + frameRight.getWidth() + "==" +  dim.width);
        break;
    }
    frameRight.setLocation(i, 0);
}
```

Ну чтобы посмотреть лог, но все очевидно **1536==1536**
...и многое другое, но никак не могу понять **как вычислить это пространство и минусануть его при позиционировании?**
Ну и:

```
getLocation() = java.awt.Point[x=1036,y=0]
getLocationOnScreen() = java.awt.Point[x=1036,y=0]
```

По сути это получается просто медиум-математическая задача. Фреймы остаются неизменными при zoom-е, т.е. они по отношению к экрану - уменьшаются. Осталось вычислить их реальный размер на экране (так как getWith() выдает то, что в setSize(?,?)) и на сколько они увеличиваются при зуме. Но ведь увеличивается то весь экран, а не фреймы по отдельности. Поэтому задача для меня встала...
27.02.18
Поигрался руками и вот что получилось простым перебором чисел:

```
Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
if (screen.width == 1920) {
    // 100% минус 500px
    setLocation(screen.width - getWidth(), 0);
} else
if (screen.width == 1536) {
    // 125% минус 600px
    setLocation(screen.width - getWidth() + getWidth() / 100 * (dpi - 100), 0);
} else
if (screen.width == 1280) {
    // 150% минус 667px
    setLocation(screen.width - getWidth() + getWidth() / 100 * (dpi - 87) + 2, 0);
} else
if (screen.width == 1098) {
    // 175% минус 712px
    setLocation(screen.width - getWidth() + getWidth() / 100 * (dpi - 78) + 2, 0);
}
```

Но это все только для моего экрана, а для других опять будет возня с перебором чисел...

Comment: обычно такое выравнивание делается с помощью лаяутов, делается панель (с параметром развертки на весь экран) из 3 столбцов, 2 строк, для 1 столбца и 1 строки устанавливается выравнивание левый верхний край, 3 столбец 1 строка выравнивание по правому верхнему краю, настраиваем ширину столбцов и высоту строк, все остальное делаем невидимым. При таком подходе можно грид дробить на сколько угодное количество частей и не парится с их позиционированием

Comment: Спасибо. Но это совсем не вариант для меня, иначе бы я не расписывал все здесь. На экране должны быть только два фрейма и контент за ними должен фокусится, как и сами фреймы по отдельности.